# Solr full index error related to mime type

Tags: tomcat, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

When running the full index I am getting the error related to mime type. Error says that Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. And after this error, index.html is printed in the log.

i am not able to access the solr URL from browser. URL from the exception is like this [solrurlfromlog](http://example.com:8989/solr/master_product)

But the solr admin console URL is below, which is working

[actualsolrurl](http://example.com:8989/solr/#/master_product)

.....

I am not getting how the URL is without /solr/#/master_product in the exception logs

As i am getting a bad url([solrurlfromlog](http://example.com:8989/solr/master_product)) in exception logs

Comment: Do you have code where this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Generally we get this error for a long http url. There is limit on http query parameter length. For default solr works with **GET** method. If your query long then the limit, solr giving error in html format. Check the real reason, if your problem about the url limit, change the working method to the **POST**.

Comment: It's more like what @MatsLindh said. What you described is just an error that causes the return of a text/html

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is caused by a misconfigured Solr server - i.e. it throws an error page (which is `text/html` by default) instead of the expected response.

The Solr log will tell you what the issue is and why the error was returned.